# How to effectively combine disconnected csr matrices in python?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I have two scipy sparse matrices matrix_1 and matrix_2. Their dimensions are as follows:

```
<628x628 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
<411x411 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
```

I am trying to combine these two matrices in a way that two disconnected matrices will be in a single csr matrix.

For examle, let's say two matrices are

```
  1 2 3      1 2 3
1 0 0 1    1 1 1 0
2 1 0 1    2 1 1 1
3 1 1 0    3 0 1 0
```

and after the operation, the result should be

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6          1 2 3 4 5 6
1 0 0 1              1 0 0 1 0 0 0
2 1 0 1              2 1 0 1 0 0 0
3 1 1 0           => 3 1 1 0 0 0 0
4       1 1 0        4 0 0 0 1 1 0
5       1 1 1        5 0 0 0 1 1 1
6       0 1 0        6 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

I have checked the documentation of the scipy, and found `vstack` and `hstack` functions, but they did not work since the dimensions of the matrices are not the same. Even though the dimensions hold, they wouldn't give the result I want since these two graphs are disconnected.

I have checked these stackoverflow questions:

[scipy append all rows of one sparse matrix to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503165/scipy-append-all-rows-of-one-sparse-matrix-to-another)
[How to concatenate two matrices in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879313/how-to-concatenate-two-matrices-in-python)

and many more unrelated posts but I couldn't come up with an effective solution. The only idea I have found is to convert csr matrices to dictionaries, append them and convert it to a csr matrix back but it seems highly inefficient.
Is there an efficient way to do this with scipy and python?

Thank you for your assistance in advance!

Comment: `sparse.vstack` actually uses `bmat`.  That in turn combines the `coo` attributes of the matrices, to make the inputs of a new matrix.  Read the code.

Comment: Did you see `block_diag` in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) suggested in the comments,

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
combined_matrix = sp.bmat([[graph_1, None], [None, graph_2]], format="csr")
```

solved my problem.